# Angular test - DOM updating on element click

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have a test and before test I'm doing such stuff.
- Going to some element
- Hovering element and small tooltip with 2 button gonna show
- I'm clicking on one of buttons and modal

```
var fireEvent = function(element, event) {

        if (element.fireEvent) {
            element.fireEvent('on' + event);
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
            evObj.initEvent(event, true, false);
            element.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    };
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser().navigateTo('/');
        sleep(5);
        var promise = function() {
            element('.browse-packshot-item').query(function(elements, done) {
                var first_element = elements.eq(0);
                fireEvent(first_element[0],'mouseover');
                sleep(2);
                element('#browse-packshots-flyout .browse-packshots-flyout-action').click();
                done();
            });
        };
        promise();

    });
```

My question are:
- It seem like lots is going on in before but I have to test if there are some elements in this model window and all this action must take place before.
- Can  you guide me for better solution - maybe use angular events on elements rather then looking for elements?

Cheers,

Comment: sounds to me like it should be part of the *actual test* rather than the *before method*.

Comment: It is tested in separate test this hover state but before showing model window with clicking element that will show up on hover I have to do this actions.

Comment: this question may fit better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).